# Continue the loop search when Rselenium returns error "NoSuchElement"

Tags: r

I use Rselenium to scrapt the "rent" information in advertisement from the website. However, it seems like not every advertisement contains the rent information. Therefore, when my loop runs to those don't have the rent information, it faced the error i.e. 'NoSuchElement' and the loop stops. I want to:

1/ fill "NA" values to those cases which dont have rent information; and

2/ continue the loop to scrapt rent information.

I already tried "tryCatch" function, however, it seems doesnt work.R still throws me an error i.e. *"Error:      Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method"*.

My code is in the below. I appreciate your time and help.

```
#add url
url <- "https://www.toimitilat.fi/toimitilahaku/?size_min=&size_max=&deal_type%5B%5D=1&language=fin&result_type=list&advanced=0&gbl=1&ref=main#searchresult"  
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate(url)

 <  for(i in 8:13){ 
  Sys.sleep(0.86)
  rent <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", paste("#objectList > div:nth-child(", i, ") > div.infoCont > div.priceCont", sep = ""))$getElementText()
  #checking if there is a rent or not
  if(!is.null(rent)){
    tryCatch({
      rent <- unlist(strsplit(rent[[1]][1], "\n"))
      rent_df <- rbind(rent_df, rent)
  }, error = function(e){
    return("NoSuchElement")
    i = i + 1
    })
  }
}
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this much more easily with `rvest` rather than using the sledgehammer of `RSelenium`.  It also copes much better with missing information.

To get a dataframe with the addresses and rents, you can use `html_nodes` to create a list of the boxes containing the information, and then `html_node` to find the relevant information in each one.  There will be one entry for each box, and any missing data will just appear as `NA`.

```
library(dplyr) #only needed for the pipe operator %>%
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.toimitilat.fi/toimitilahaku/?size_min=&size_max=&deal_type%5B%5D=1&language=fin&result_type=list&advanced=0&gbl=1&ref=main#searchresult"  

boxes <- read_html(url) %>%                      #read the page
      html_nodes(".infoCont")                    #find the info boxes

address <- boxes %>% 
      html_node("h4 > a") %>%                    #find the address info in each box
      html_text()

rent <- boxes %>% 
      html_node(".priceCont") %>%                #find the rent info in each box
      html_text() %>%                            #extract the text
      trimws()                                   #trim whitespace

#put together in a dataframe
rent_df <- data.frame(address = address,   
                      rent = rent,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(rent_df)
                       address                                             rent
1           Akaa, Airolantie 5 Myyntihinta: \nMyydään tarjousten perusteella...
2           Akaa, Hämeentie 18                                             <NA>
3     Akaa, Hämeentie 69, Akaa           
4          Akaa, Keskuskatu 42                    Vuokrahinta: \n300 e/kk + alv
5 Akaa, Kirkkotori 10, Toijala                               Vuokrahinta: \n450
6  Akaa, Palomäentie 6 Toijala                         Vuokrahinta: \n3€/m2+alv
```

You can then easily extract the information you need.

Comment: thanks Andew. Thats a very simple and easy code to get information that i need. However, i also want to pair address and rent information after scrapping.  For example: 


`address <- read_html(url) %>%                       
  html_nodes(".infoCont > .titleCont") %>%  
  html_text() %>%                         
  trimws()
`
`> address %>% length()
[1] 25`

Comment: in this case, address lengtth and rent length is different, and hence i dont know how to match them based on index number. That's why i though of Rselenium and fill error for cases which rent doesnt exist. f is there is any good solution to pair address and rent in Rvest, I would appreciate your suggestion a lot.

Comment: @KattyNguyen I've updated the answer to show how to do this.  The trick is to identify the information boxes on the page and then look for the information within each of them - that guarantees that the various items stay together.

Comment: Genius :D. Fast and very simple code. Thanks a lot for your answer. 
Btw, I like your coding style, intuitive and easy to read :)

Comment: Hi again, I came across with scraping task again and applied the same rvest solution. However, this time I couldn't find a "box" since each page result tied to a unique id. For example:

url <- https://toimitilat.kauppalehti.fi/List?t=81%2C82%2C83%2C84&c=2&mhp=1&on=PublishDate&od=-1&p=20

First box contains information i need is "//*[@id="estate158002166"]/div/div[2]"., 2nd box "//*[@id="estate158006349"]/div/div[2]" and so on. So I wonder is there any way i could scrap it without knowing exact id number. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: @KattyNguyen There are nested boxes here.  The `estate158002166` actually has an internal one called `row  tk-list-item` which contains everything you need.  So something like `html_nodes(".tk-list-item")` might be what you need in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `rvest` should be easier, but if you want or need to use `RSelenium`, this should work:

```
# Preparation
library(dplyr)                                     # required for bind_rows 

# add url
url <- "https://www.toimitilat.fi/toimitilahaku/?size_min=&size_max=&deal_type%5B%5D=1&language=fin&result_type=list&advanced=0&gbl=1&ref=main#searchresult"  
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(url)

# Checking that rD and remDr objects exist and work
## If youg get an error here, that means that selenium objects doesn´t work - usually because ports are busy, selenium server or client have not been closed properly or browser drivers are out of date (or something else)
class(rD)
class(remDr)

# making separate function retrieving the rent and handling exceptions
giveRent <- function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(0.86)
  tryCatch( {
    rent <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", paste("#objectList > div:nth-child(", i, ") > div.infoCont > div.priceCont", sep = ""))$getElementText()
    rent <- unlist(strsplit(rent[[1]][1], "\n"))
    rent <- rent[2]}
    , warning = function(e){rent <<- NA}
    , error = function(e){rent <<- NA})
  return(rent)}

# adding rent to the dataframe in for-loop
rent_df <- c()
for(i in 1:33){rent_df <- bind_rows(rent_df, (data.frame(giveRent(i))))}
print(rent_df)
```